# I'm getting a 403 (Forbidden) error when I try to publish a .NET Framework package to a repo in one of our GH organizations

Tags: github, nuget

I've been struggling with this issue since [May of this year](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/54975). I've got some old .NET Framework DLLs, that I'm trying to put into the Packages of a GitHub repo in one of our organizations, in our GitHub Enterprise account. I don't have the source code for these DLLs, so I've been creating the nuspec file using the `nuget spec` command at a PowerShell prompt. I've been following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) to do this, while working with just the DLL file. After I create the nuspec file I added a folder "lib\net452" where I moved the DLL file following [this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#framework-version-folder-structure). After that I ran the `nuget pack` command to generate the nupkg file. Following the instructions for [publishing with a NuGet CLI](https://github.com/NuGet/docs.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/main/docs/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework.md#publish-with-the-nuget-cli), I used a personal access token I previously created, to try to push the nupkg to the repo in our enterprise | organization. This is the command I used at a PowerShell prompt:

`nuget push CentralRegistry.dll.1.0.0.nupkg <<my Classic GitHub token>> -src https://github.com/OUR_ORGANIZATION/DDSD_DLLs/package`

But that only raises an error that says:

> Forbidden https://github.com/OUR_ORGANIZATION/DDSD_DLLs/package
> 403 (Forbidden)

My PAT has write:packages, read:packages, and delete:packages permissions.

I don't see what I've done wrong. I've followed everything as best I understand it in all the references I've listed above. Please show me what mistake(s) I've made.

Comment: This sound a bit like a [Superuser](https://superuser.com) question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow these steps:

#### You should set up it only once.

- Open the **Package Manager Console**, type and run this command below

  - Before running the command, make sure you have replaced the variables below
  - You must replace the **YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME** with your GitHub username (it's not your email, it's your username)
  - You must replace the **TOKEN** with the generated token (it's not your personal password, it's the token)
  - You must replace the **YOUR_ORGANIZATION** with your organization name
  - You should replace the **PROJECT_NAME** with a friendly name that makes sense for this project.
  - **Command:** *dotnet nuget add source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/YOUR_ORGANIZATION/index.json" --name "PROJECT_NAME" --username "YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME" --password "TOKEN"*

#### How to publish packages?

Run this command below every time you have to publish a new package version.

- Open the **Package Manager Console**, type and run this command below.

  **Note:** Make sure you have changed to your nupkg path

  - *dotnet nuget push ".\YourProject\bin\Release\CentralRegistry.1.0.0.nupkg" -s "PROJECT_NAME"*
- To see the generated packages, open the link:
  https://github.com/orgs/YOUR_ORGANIZATION/packages/nuget/package/YOUR_PROJECT